# fix bad sector all booting

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive

every time I turn on my note appears a check disk on / home and asks if I want to correct the sectors in error, I put yes, it takes a long time but if I reboot, appears again. what do i do?

Comment: Please add more info such as exact errors, recent updates ect

Comment: every time he starts running fsck automatically at boot and I press f to fix bad sectors, bad again when you start is the same.

Comment: I read that what im asking is EXACTLY what is the error.

Comment: Your hard drive is likely failing and bad sectors can not be fixed. Back up your data. You can reformat the partition(s) and during the formatting process bad sectors will be marked as unusable. This may extend the life of the drive, but, total disk failure can occur at any time with no additional warning.

Comment: Erro log http://pastebin.com/CURkFuTW

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for posting this as an answer, but comments would not get the attention this needs.  It is my considered opinion, **that your drive is in imminent danger of failing.**

### Please make a full system backup right now.

If you don't know how to make a system backup, please refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc).  You're user type 4. If you need any further help on making a system backup, leave a comment below this answer.

What???  You're still here?  Go away and make the system back-up first! (Disk-to-image)

Then, boot from a LiveCD and issue the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

Then:

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
```

and post the output of that to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide a link to the ouput back here.  Then:

```
sudo smartctl --test=short /dev/sda
```

Wait for 5 minutes and post the output of that (by doing another `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda`) to http://paste.ubuntu.com too and provide that link to its output back here too.

## Hopefully I'm wrong

and I can delete this answer safely and we can get back to speeding up your boot process...